# Disable a particular application (like Youtube) using an Android Program code .

Tags: android

I want to only disable an application (not delete it) using android code.

Please provide me some sample code to block or disable application using android code.

It will be very needful for me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done on unrooted phones. Third party applications do not have permission to block other third party applications.

If this was allowed, it would be pandemonium!